# how to create generic object for a class

Tags: .net, generics

How do I create a function which will accept generic object of class as an argument and will also have  a generic return type?

Answer (score 2):

If you want the same generic for the input and return types then:

```
public T DoSomething<T>(T input)
```

If you want different generics for the input and return types then:

```
public TReturn DoSomething<TInput, TReturn>(TInput input)
```

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
 public T Method<T>(T param)
```

the method may take as manay generic parameters as are needed to specify the types of the various input and return parameters, so you may also do this:

```
public T1 Method<T1,T2,T3>(T1 input1, T2 input2, T3 input3);
```

some information on generic methods on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx)